# ComboBox selected item binding not showing the initial value - then working OK

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I have a weird problem with something simple I suppose. 
I have a combobox with two bindings set up - one for ItemsSource and another for SelectedItem.
The selected item is not working on initial startup, but then it works OK. Output does not indicate any binding problems, I have also set up a TextBlock with the same binding to see if it works - and it does.

Here's the code

```
  <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsEditable="False"
                          Name="ProgramsCollectionComboBox"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ThisUc,
                                                 Path=SelectedProgram}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisUc,
                                                Path=ProgramsCollection}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisUc, 
                     Path=SelectedProgram.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The property:

```
        private Program _selectedProgram;
        public Program SelectedProgram
        {
            get
            {
                if (_selectedProgram == null)
                {
                        _selectedProgram = new Program(Settings.Default.SelectedProgramPath);
                }
                return _selectedProgram;

            }
        set
        {
                _selectedProgram = value;
                Settings.Default.SelectedProgramPath = SelectedProgram.PathProgramFolder;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProgram");
        }
    }
```

It saves and reads the settings OK, the initial values is shown in the textblock below the combobox, when I change the selected item, the textblock is updated, the settings are changed and everything works fine - except for the fact that on app startup, selected item is not selected.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The getter of your property should return a value of your ProgramsCollection and not a new instance if it is null

Comment: @Jehof At initial start up, it should be null, therefore it should return the new `Program` anyway.

Comment: yes, but the new Programm is not part of your ProgrammsCollection. This is the cause why the initial value is not displayed, but afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons your initial binding is not working. First, as Jehof has mentioned himself, is the fact that you're setting your `SelectedProgram` to an item that is not part of the `ProgramsCollection`.

Furthermore, when you are setting the initial value of your `SelectedProgram` you are doing so in the getter, where `PropertyChanged` is not invoked and thus the binding will never be aware of that change. You can either invoke `PropertyChanged` when initializing it in the getter:

```
...
get
{
    if (_selectedProgram == null)
    {
        _selectedProgram = _programsCollection?.FirstOrDefault();
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProgram");
    }
    return _selectedProgram;
}
...
```

Or even better, set the default value on the private field:

```
private Program _selectedProgram = _programsCollection?.FirstOrDefault();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The getter of your property `SelectedProgram` should return a value of your `ProgrammsCollection` and not a new instance if it is null.

If the value is not part of the collection that is bound to the combobox it is not displayed.